# goal seek macro scanning across multiple rows and column

Tags: excel, vba

[this is the code i used to solve for the requirement on one using goal seek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcv4s.png)

[this is a screenshot of the excel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4SN9.png)

**i am new to this forum so i don't know how to include the code and excel file to avoid confusion but please let me know if you more clarification**

**i need to specify the row "Days of stock" and "requirement" so the code i used for just one of the product can loop through all the product and solve the requirement using goal seek **

```
Sub updateRequirement()

Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer

Dim lastcol As Integer, j As Integer


With ActiveSheet

 lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
 lastcol = Cells(12, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 
    For i = finalrow To 12 Step -1
    For j = 5 To lastcol Step 1
    
       If Cells(i, j).Value = "days of stock" Then
            Cells(1, j - 1).Value = "Requirement"
            
    
    Cells(i, j).GoalSeek Goal:=30, ChangingCell:=Cells(i, j - 1)
   
         End If
   
   Next j
   Next i
   
   
End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add the column and row headers to your screenshot?

Comment: i updated the excel screen shot

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know the formula for the "Days of Stock" cells? I know that first row refers to "Ending Inventory" of previous month and that "Ending Inventory" is the sum of first row, "In Transit", "PO's", "Requirement" minus "Demand".

Comment: This is the formula used for days of stock {=IFERROR(IF(D12<=D16,30*D12/D16,IF(D12<SUM(D16:E16),30+30*D12/SUM(D16:E16),IF(D12<SUM(D16:F16),60+30*D12/SUM(D16:F16),IF(D12<SUM(D16:G16),90+30*D12/SUM(D16:G16),120)))),0)}

Comment: Thank you. The reason why CDP1802's code did not work, was a different writing in the texts ("Requirement" and "Days of Stock". He already updated the code of his answer by adding the LCase command. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan down column "C" for "Days of Stock" but remember last occurrence of "Requirement".

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub updateRequirement()

    Const TARGET = 30

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long, iReqRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Integer, c As Integer
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
    
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(12, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     
        For r = 12 To lastRow
            If LCase(.Cells(r, "C")) = "requirement" Then
                iReqRow = r
            ElseIf LCase(.Cells(r, "C")) = "days of stock" Then
                For c = 5 To lastCol
                    If .Cells(r, c) < TARGET Then
                       .Cells(r, c).GoalSeek _
                            Goal:=TARGET, _
                            ChangingCell:=.Cells(iReqRow, c - 1)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next r
       
    End With
    MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: out of curiosity why is the c in quote""

Comment: @coreylameen "C" refers to column C, or you could change to 3

Comment: oh okay thank you so much. couldnt figure out how to private chat. but is there a way to prevent the requirement from going to a negative number while trying to archive the target number

Comment: @coreylameen I don't think so but you could try adding `if .Cells(iReqRow, c - 1) < 0 then .Cells(iReqRow, c - 1) =0` after the `.GoalSeek` line.